# Table '#temptable' does not exist when executing drop table [#temptable] from code behind

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, winforms, temp-tables

I'm using a bulkcopy to a temp table that then will be used to MERGE to the main table. All is working but when I try dropping my temp table, I get an error saying 'Table '#temptable' does not exist'

Basically I do the following.

```
        'get data from excel to a datatable.
   Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlstring, excelConnection)
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())  

        'create sql connection
  Using sqlcon As SqlConnection =
            New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLCON").ConnectionString)
                sqlcon.Open()
                'create temp table
                Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("create table #tbltemp (ID int, FirstName nvarchar(50),LastName nvarchar(50),JobDesc nvarchar(50))", sqlcon)
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Try
                'start bulcopy
                    Using bulkcopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(sqlcon)

                        'map columns
                        Dim mapID As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("ID", "ID")
                        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapTMID)
                        Dim mapFName As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("FirstName", "FirstName")
                        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapFName)
                        Dim mapLName As New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("LastName", "LastName")
                        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapLName)
                    End Using 'end bulkcopy using
                    'Inserts new records to main from temptable
                    Dim mergesql As String = "merge into dbo.Main as Target " & _
                              "using #tbltemp as Source " & _
                              "on " & _
                              "(Target.ID = Source.ID) " & _
                              "when not matched then " & _
                              "insert (ID,FirstName,LastName) values (Source.ID,Source.FirstName,Source.LastName);"
                    sqlcmd.CommandText = mergesql
                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    'Clean up stuff
                      cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE [#tbltemp]"
                      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


                Catch ex As Exception
                    Response.Write(ex.Message)
                Finally
'close sql con
                    sqlcon.Close()

                End Try
                'close excel con
                excelConnection.Close()
            End Using ' end using sqlcon
```

Like I said, everything seems to be working except for dropping the table. Does this means that temp table has been dropped automatically?

I tried running some tests and searched around but no luck.

Comment: Are you able to construct a *short* but *complete* example that demonstrates the problem? At the moment, there's obviously bits missing from the "code" and they may actually be important. But it's tricky to tell without being able to take this code and run it for ourselves. It doesn't have to be the real code - just something that shows the actual problem (i.e. check yourself that the sample actually has the behaviour before editing it into your question)

Comment: I edited and put more of the real code. I may just close the connection and that should clear all temp tables like TMVector suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmd is the OleDbcommand associated with you excelconnection and not a SqlCommand associated with your Database connection.

Incidently, I use this technique all the time and you can also create the temporary table as...

```
Select Top 0 * Into #tbltemp From dbo.Main
```

This save on defining the columns in a static create table statement.

Also if you are working with temp tables a lot within the same connection then you can check it exists and drop it using...

```
If Object_Id('TempDB..#tbltemp') Is Not Null Drop Table #tbltemp
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will automatically drop temp tables when the connection closes, so there isn't actually any need for you to do this.

Not sure why it is failing on the drop part though. You might not have the right permissions.